# Plot to PDF: text is rendered improperly

Tags: autocad, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to use Autodesk Forge platform's design automation service to compose some drawing on the fly, and output it as PDF. The composition part is working well, but when it is converted to PDF, the texts are not rendered properly. If I try to do the same conversion on the desktop, using the same AutoCAD version (2016 aka 20.1), it is working just fine.

I have created a simple test case to illustrate the issue.

The dwg file:
[image: dwg screenshot]
[demo.dwg](https://ufile.io/xsb9n)

The resulting PDF when converted with local AutoCAD installation:
[image: local result]

The resulting PDF when converted through the Forge:
[image: forge result]

In both cases, the conversion is done by using the following script:

```
-plot
Yes
Model
AutoCAD PDF (High Quality Print).pc3
ISO expand A4 (210.00 x 297.00 MM)
Millimeters
Landscape
No
Extents
Fit
Center
Yes
monochrome.ctb
Yes
As
test
No
Yes
```

Looking at the generated comment, I have come across the following link:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Drawing-text-appears-as-Comments-in-a-PDF-created-by-AutoCAD.html

So it looks like the issue has something to do with SHX text. However, I have no idea why it works fine on my local machine, and because of that, I'm also not sure how to fix the issue. The AutoCAD version installed on my machine is 2016 version without SP1 (and I confirmed that the command EPDFSHX does not exist in it).

Can anyone tell me why it works on my local machine, and is there any way to have it working the same way on the Forge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have  updated our `Forge Design Automation` service recently with the addition of `Arial Narrow` TrueType font, you should get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because we don't have the Arial Narrow font available on our servers. It turns out that we have the license so we will update soon to include it.

Comment: Hi Albert, is there any ETA when this update will happen?